# End-to-end correlation for API Management, Functions and ServiceBus

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-api-management

I have a problem regarding the end-to-end correlation of a process chain on Azure. After seeing this great [article](http://mlogdberg.com/2019/02/functions/understandhowlogsinai) from Mattias Lögdberg, I wanted to achieve a correlation chain as depicted here:
[image: Desired state]
By following Mattias steps, I've managed to achieve this, BUT when slightly modifying the chain by removing the second step and directly posting messages into the queue, the chain gets broken.

**New Setup**

1. **User** calls **API Management**
2. **API Management** calls **ServiceBus** (via REST)
3. **ServiceBus** triggers **Function**
4. **Function** calls **API Management** (Functions v3)

[image: Call chain]

In the first call, the *Diagnostic-Id* header is set to the w3c-traceparent [standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/#examples-of-http-traceparent-headers), so the ServiceBus message can correlate. This happens by executing following policy in the inbound section:

```
<set-header name="Diagnostic-Id" exists-action="override">
    <value>@($"00-{context.RequestId.ToString("N")}-{String.Format("{0:x16}", new Random().Next(0x1000000))}-00")</value>
</set-header>
```

I've tried out several variations of this header, but this one at least got me to following flow:
[image: Current flow]

Is there something I am missing to "summarize" the logs properly?
All operations have the same operation_Id and different operation_parentId's - exactly as in the process with the function.

**+++ Update 19/11 +++**

A new finding I made is, that the correlation depends on the Request-Id header. But as the ServiceBus expects a "Diagnostic-Id", the APIM generated Request-Id is ignored. Nevertheless, the best workaround to "catch em all" I found is as follows:

```
<set-header name="Diagnostic-Id" exists-action="override">
    <value>@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Request-Id", context.RequestId.ToString("N")}</value>
</set-header>
```

This makes sure, that the caller id is taken into respect. If there's no caller Request-Id, the apim generated request id is defaulted. It's still not the view with the "Time Spent in Queue"-feature, but at least it's a comprehensible solution.

Comment: The document you've linked to talks about `traceparent` header where the code above sets `Diagnostic-id`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Check following link:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-end-to-end-tracing.md#distributed-tracing-and-correlation-through-service-bus-messaging

Comment: I've raised an issue related to this here: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2153